# Django: How can I make a part of the URL optional

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a url in which I would like to make the status token optional. If the status token is not provided in the url I give a default value in the view method argument. I tried replacing the token with this `(?:/(?P<status>\d+))?$` but doesn't seems to work well. Thanks

```
url(r'^(?P<status>\d+)/$', frequest_list, name="frequest_list"),

def request_list(request, status=1):
 ...
 ...
```

Update:
This was the pattern I was trying:

```
url(r'^(?:/(?P<status>\d+))?$', frequest_list, name="frequest_list"),
```

So, if I try `localhost/features/` works well

But if I do `localhost/features/1/` it fails

Comment: Why doesn't it work well? I use that same single url, optional capture approach.

Comment: It gives me 404 saying none of the urls matched. Am I missing something in that?

Comment: Can you post the exact patterns you have tried?

Comment: @jdi: Updated the question. Please take a look

Answer (score 3):

Just create a second url entry that calls the same view:

```
url(r'^features/$', frequest_list, name="frequest_list_default"),
url(r'^features/(?P<status>\d+)/$', frequest_list, name="frequest_list"),
```

Comment: I actually want to include some more optional filters so, trying to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

I use single url optional captures in some of my projects, and they work fine. You might want to adjust your pattern to make the trailing `/` optional. I think that is what is causing your url to not match. Django does have an "APPEND_SLASH" settings bool that will add that on to your urls if they are missing it and don't match:

```
url(r'^features(?:/(?P<status>\d+))?/?$', frequest_list, name="frequest_list")
```

The optional `/` could probably also be written like this:

```
url(r'^features/?(?:(?P<status>\d+)/?)?$', frequest_list, name="frequest_list")
```

Comment: If I try the first one, I get the same 404 error. Where as in the second case its showing up as __nothing to repeat__

Comment: I am removing the __features__ part in the url. Updated the question please take a look.

Comment: I use that same first pattern in my own code and it works fine. Not sure where it's going wrong for you.

Comment: I see, I will keep trying will keep you posted as soon as I get something